# How to run a project running on wamp/xampp server using system's IP address in place of localhost?

Tags: php, web-applications, ip-address, xampp, wamp

Actually I'm making a web project using Wamp server, and to run the same I access it using the usual local-host address, as we do while building a project on our PC. But to share my project with my friends, I want to make access using the IP address of my computer. 
But when I make such an access it is not able to connect, which is not the case with my friend's project.

After I failed accessing using the Wamp Server, I installed Xamp Server, the project can be accessed using local host with both the servers (running one at a time) but not when accessed using my PC's IP address (which I find using http://www.whatismyip.com/)

Please Help me Sort out the problem, so that I can share my project with my friends and get a feedback from them.

Comment: Kind of off-topic for this site, I'm afraid as I think you need to configure your router to forward traffic from your public IP (as discovered by the site you mentioned) to your LAN IP Address.

Comment: Have you checked off for put the server online? Until the server is put online in wamp it will only be reachable from localhost. (Might be set online by default tho, not 100% sure)

Comment: Adapt the Listen directive in httpd.conf.

Answer (score 1):

First check the `Listen` directive in apache's configuration file (usually `httpd.conf`). If it only listens on `127.0.0.1` then it can not be accessed on your network interface.

You can also check it with:

```
netstat -na
```

You should see that port `80` is litening on all interfaces as somthing like:

```
  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

If this is the case then you should check the access to your port 80 from the outside world. First of all firewalls can block the access to it. If you are behind a NAT (router) then you should use it's port forwading settings to open port 80 (or other arbitrary port) on the router an forward it to the port 80 on your PC.